# Conditionally add data-attributes in Jekyll

Tags: if-statement, yaml, jekyll, liquid, yaml-front-matter

My basic YAML Front Matter for blog posts looks as:

```
   layout: post
   title:  'Crepes'
   permalink: /crepes/
   src: '/assets/images/crepes.jpg' 
   date:   2018-05-24 21:41:00
   origin: http//...
   ingredients: 
    - ingredient1: amount
    - ingredient2: amount
```

Here is my index.html to display entries:

```
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}

<li data-title='{{ post.title }}' data-origin="{{ post.origin }}"
    data-src="{{ post.src | prepend: relative_url}}" 
    data-content='{ "ingredients": {{ post.ingredients | jsonify }} }'>

    <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}">
        <img src="{{ post.src | prepend: relative_url }}" alt={{ post.title }}/>
    </a>

</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**The problem is:**
Some posts are supposed to have no origin value, like `origin:`. And I am looking for a way to add data-origin attribute only if it's value specified in YAML Front Matter.

Liquid give following option:

```
{% if condition %}
    <li>....</li>
{% endif %}
```

Is there any way to use it inside of html tag? In my case I expect something like this:

```
 {% for post in site.posts %}

 <li  
     {% if post.origin has value %}
         data-origin="{{ post.origin }}"
     {% endif %}">      
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I see four cases :

- `post.origin` is not present in front matter : 
  `post.origin == null`
- `post.origin` is present in front matter, but not set (`post.origin:`)
  => post.origin == null`
- `post.origin` is present in front matter, but set to empty string (`post.origin: ""`)
  => `post.origin == ""`
- `post.origin` is present in front matter, and set to valid string (`post.origin: "toto"`)
  => `post.origin == "toto"`

Results are conform to [Truthy and falsy Liquid documentation](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/truthy-and-falsy/).

From there, using [logical liquid operators](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/operators/), we can build a condition like :

```
<li
  {% if post.origin and post.origin != "" %}
     data-origin="{{ post.origin }}"{% endif %}>
</li>
```

Note that `post.origin` means `post.origin != null`.